# Flutter Packages Get Failed

Tags: charts, dart, sdk, flutter

I am trying to add this library to my flutter project: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/charts_flutter#-installing-tab-

When I add the dependency to my pubspec.yaml file and hit packages get, I get the following error:

> The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.9.4.flutter-f9ebf21297.
>
> Because charts_flutter >=0.6.0 depends on charts_common >=0.6.0 which
>   requires SDK version >=2.1.0 <3.0.0, charts_flutter >=0.6.0 is
>   forbidden. So, because undaunted_golf_flutter depends on
>   charts_flutter ^0.6.0, version solving failed.
>
> pub get failed (1) Process finished with exit code 1

To me, it looks like I have the most up to date version of Dart, which matches the minimum version the chart_common library requires. I updated my Android Studio yesterday (2/15/2019), the same day the charts_flutter and charts_common were updated.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.9.4.flutter-f9ebf21297.
>
> ... charts_flutter ... requires SDK version >=2.1.0 <3.0.0

This means you need to update your Flutter installation.

Either `flutter upgrade` or if that doesn't result in a new enough Flutter version,

use

```
flutter channel dev
flutter doctor
```

or alternatively use an older `charts_flutter` version than `>=0.6.0` that does not depend on `<= 2.1.0-dev`

Comment: I tried flutter upgrade. Here is what comes back:

/Users/duffette/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color upgrade
Upgrading Flutter from /Users/duffette/flutter...
Already up to date.

Upgrading engine...
Already up-to-date.

Flutter 1.0.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5391447fae (3 months ago) • 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
Engine • revision 7375a0f414
Tools • Dart 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

Comment: Then you need to switch to `dev` channel to get newer Flutter versions until the next stable channel update is released (or use an older `charts_flutter` package.