# Dart 2.6 and Flutter, Upgrading Dependency

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, dependencies, upgrade

Using Flutter, I am trying to update my dart dependency 2.6.0 but I get an error

```
Because *project_name* requires SDK version >=2.6.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1)
exit code 1
```

I want to use the new features that dart offers, such as Extension Methods. How could I go about upgrading my dependency? I have installed the newest stable version of dart on my computer, but regardless I still get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things that might help:

From this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21421), you can try ensuring that you've updated `enviroment` in your `pubspec.yaml` file like so:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"
```

Another thing that might help is just double checking the steps in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54724516/10576762) or on the [dart installation page](https://dart.dev/get-dart) to ensure that you've updated to the latest version correctly.